Valgrind (C): Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
I am doing a school project on AVL tree in C. And the code is presenting the following errors. It compiles nicely but it is terminating with Segmentation fault (core dumped).
==210456== Invalid read of size 8
==210456==    at 0x1095B5: rotate_left (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x10968C: rotate_double_right (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109C6E: treat_shrink_left (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109DBC: remove_leftmost_son (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109E15: actual_remove (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x10A098: remove_info (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109FB6: remove_info (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x10A31E: main (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==210456== 
==210456== 
==210456== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==210456==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==210456==    at 0x1095B5: rotate_left (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x10968C: rotate_double_right (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109C6E: treat_shrink_left (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109DBC: remove_leftmost_son (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109E15: actual_remove (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x10A098: remove_info (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x109FB6: remove_info (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==    by 0x10A31E: main (in /home/asteria/Documents/MC202/MC202_024/lab05/main)
==210456==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==210456==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==210456==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==210456==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==210456==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.

I need to make sense out of this, but I am strugling. Can someone help?
Thank u! :)

This is a typical ACCESS VIOLATION which indicates you are attempting to read 8 bytes from illegal address.
use -g parameter to compile your program:
gcc <yourappsource> -g <other compiler parameters your compiler needs>

This will show you line number in valgrind and you can investigate if there is any out-of-bounds or mistake in pointer operations.

==210456== Invalid read of size 8
...
==210456==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

That means that you are trying to read something of size 8 (a pointer, double or long on LP64 systems) from address 0x18.
The most likely cause of that is accessing a field through a NULL pointer.
Let's say you have a C++ tree structure like this:
struct Tree
{
   Tree* parent;
   Tree* left;
   Tree* right;
};

And then you have a function
Tree* next(Tree* elem)
{
   if (elem->right)
   {
       etc etc.
   }
}

What happens if you call next with a NULL pointer?
The code that the compiler generated for if (elem->right) will roughly be
read regX, memory pointer elem plus offsetof(Tree, right)
test regX

and if "memory pointer elem" is 0 that will boil down to
read regX, 0 + 0x18
resulting in the kind of error that you got.
